Wrapping Class Types in a Namespace
I'm trying to create an intermediate 'Wrapper' Library. My project has to include two libraries neither of which I can edit. The problem is one of those libraries has naming conflicts with the other, and will throw redefinition errors on compilation (specifically there are some enums defined in the headers that will conflict).
My solution was to hopefully use an intermediate, static wrapper library to create a namespace library. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to work.
My whole design here is to avoid including "MsgA.h" in the base code, and to instead use the wrapper library to alias it into a namespace. If I include "MsgA.h" into the base code, it has enum definitions in its header that will conflict with other types (thus the redefinition error).
In my Wrapper.h:
#ifndef WRAPPER_H

#define WRAPPER_H

// Forward Declarations
class MsgA;

namespace MsgLibrary {
   using MsgA = ::MsgA;
};

#endif

Then in my Wrapper.cpp:
#include "Wrapper.h"
#include "MsgA.h"

#endif
But when I try to use Wrapper.h, I get an incomplete type error and cannot compile. I'm pretty confused by this, the code is pretty simple, my hope would be in the static intermediate library I declare the symbol and then it finds the class to link. But I must be misunderstanding something.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Works here. Provide a [mcve]. Something that can be copy/pasted and used to reproduce the error/problem.

Also missing MsgA.h

You cannot just move a class definition to a separate TU and use a forward declaration instead. C++ doesn't work this way.

A key consideration is whether or not the libraries are header-only (maybe whether or not the enums are defined in their own headers). If both libraries have a binary component to link with, there could be a hidden "one definition rule" violation that would not be solved by working around the visible redefinition error. In other words, your solution might address a symptom without addressing the full problem.

"specifically there are some enums defined in the headers that will conflict" -- You say this, but then your example code forward declares a problematic class, not an enum. Which is it? Things can quickly become more complicated if there is more than just an enum involved. Examples: Wrapping external libraries in namespaces and problem wrapping extern "C" library in a namespace
